# General solution – linear differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering if anybody would be able to explain the process involved regarding the solution to the following linear differential equation:

$$ x^2 \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}+xy+1=0 $$

Thank You.

Comment: **Hint:** It is a linear equation and you can use an Integrating Factor. It can also be transformed into an Exact Equation.

Answer (score 1):

make the ansatz $y(x)=x^r$ and a special solution is given by $$y_p(x)=-\frac{\log(x)}{x}$$ 
or write
$$y'(x)+\frac{y(x)}{x}=-\frac{1}{x^2}$$
$$\mu(x)=e^{\int \frac{1}{x}dx}=x$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x(y(x))=-\frac{1}{x}$$
$$\int \frac{d}{dx}(xy(x))dx=\int-\frac{1}{x}dx$$
$$xy(x)=-\log(x)+C_1$$

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to rewrite the equation as

$$ \begin{align}
xy' + y &= -\frac{1}{x} \\
(xy)' &= -\frac{1}{x} \\
 xy &= -\ln|x| + C \\ 
y &= \frac{C-\ln|x|}{x} 
\end{align} $$

You can also follow the general method for a first-order linear ODE
$$ y' + \frac{1}{x}y = -\frac{1}{x^2} $$
and compute the integrating factor 
$$ \mu(x) = \exp{\int \frac{1}{x}\ dx} = x $$
which leads us back to the beginning
$$ xy' + y = -\frac{1}{x} $$